# get checkbox value including value after whitespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a strange problem or i did not notice before. i getting the value of checkbox using jquery. value is like this

```js
<input type = "checkbox" class = "btn btn-info" id = "dlt_btn" value= '+object.u_id+','+object.first+','+object.second+'>;
```

but the problem is this that value is sara,95,class A

but the code give me value sara,95,class

i am not getting the complete value of the check box.

Comment: what's that syntax for the value? you are using just html an vanilla js? you have `,` and `;` therem is that the actual code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how you are creating the HTML, but in the end the HTML has to look like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="btn btn-info" id="btn" value="sara,95,class A">
```

So make sure that value="..." has the correct quotes.

Comment: thanks! ur ans made me check my value quotes. it has only syntax problem.